# Java List Synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

I have an ArrayList which is accessed by multiple threads. Main thread only clears the list and others add to it. I don't want the list get cleared while another thread is adding item to it. I want the list is locked while thread is adding item to it.

this is the code of adding thread:

```
synchronized (items)
{
    int length = jsonArray.length();
    if ((length > 0)) for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        items.add(new Item(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)));
    }
}
```

But I don't use synchronized block for clearing. Is synchronized block necessary for clear too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the list get cleared while another thread is adding item to it.

Then yes, you need to have the `clear` routine `synchronized` as well.

In the below sample, the synchronized statement in `add` does not block `clear`.

```
public void add(T t) {
   synchronized(items) {
      items.add(t);
   }
}

public void clear() {
   items.clear();
}
```

Comment: So, what I get is synchronized block doesn't lock the list totally, it only locks it from other adding thread in this case?

Comment: What if some thread starts adding while the main thread is performing clear operation?

Comment: `synchronized(items)` here blocks multiple simulatenous invocations of `items.add(t)`. The `clear` routine due to lack of `synchronization` doesn't even know or care about the lock.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to handle this is to just use

```
List<Foo> items = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Foo>());
```

All the methods will be synchronized and you'll be safe.

If anyone comments here something about performance, provide actual data of the OP's scenario to back up your claims.

Comment: As I read about synchronizedList it only protect a single add, not bunch of adds.

Comment: Well, you could use addAll() to add a batch of items. Although your scenario is a bit unclear. Why is the main thread clearing the array? Is it removing the items and storing them somewhere else?

Comment: No, when user select another order I clear the list so new items get loaded from internet. If other threads add to it after clear they come at top of list.

Comment: @Ali It does, but you get around any compound operation by `synchronized(jsonArray){`.  That locks access to not only the code within the block but also all operations on the list.

Comment: You have several threads downloading information into the same List? You might want to head over to the codereview side to see if you can't improve the architecture a bit.